# How to Conditionally Size Columns to Fit in Ag-Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

We are currently using this prop in ag-grid.

```
onDisplayedColumnsChanged={event => event.api.sizeColumnsToFit()}
```

It is helpful for preventing whitespace from showing up when we hide a column, as well as keeps horizontal scrolling to a minimum when we unhide a column. We also use it for similar reasons when grouping on a particular column(s).

Unfortunately, it prevents us from using other features of Ag-Grid, such as selecting the option to resize a column to fit its contents. It also prevents columns that have been manually resized from keeping their size when they are moved somewhere else on the grid.

Is there any way to check for whether a column is being added/removed/grouped? the event object provided by the `onDisplayedColumnsChanged` prop only exposes the columnApi, api, and type properties. I haven't found anything useful in those so far.

I've considered creating a useEffect that will sizeColumnsToFit when the gridApi changes, but I believe I hit the same issue there with not having any useful properties to trigger the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell AG Grid columns to ignore **sizeColumnsToFit()** by setting the property **suppressSizeToFit** to **true**:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/#size-columns-to-fit

You can set the property on-the-fly by listening to one of the column events where auto-sizing should be disabled:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-columns